# CommandHandler not found exception with command payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I try to use a command DTO but his handler is not recognized.
When I log the DTO, it is a simple object `{...}` without `CreateUserCommand` signature.

Here is my controller :

```js
async index(@Body() createUserCommand: CreateUserCommand): Promise<User> {
    console.log(createUserCommand);
    return await this.commandBus.execute(createUserCommand);
  }
```

I get the following output :

```
 { 
    firstName: 'xxx',
    lastName: 'xxx',
    email: 'xxx@xxx.com',
    password: 'xxx'
}
```

When i try to use directly the command it is working :

```js
const command = new CreateUserCommand();
command.firstName = 'xxx';
command.lastName = 'xxx';
command.email = 'xxx@xxx.com';
command.password = 'xxx';

return await this.commandBus.execute(createUserCommand);
```

The following output :

```js
 CreateUserCommand { 
    firstName: 'xxx',
    lastName: 'xxx',
    email: 'xxx@xxx.com',
    password: 'xxx'
}
```

Is it possible to use a DTO as a command handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `@Body` it will produce a plain javascript object but not an instance of your dto class. You can use [`class-transformer`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#methods) and its `plainToClass(CreateUserCommand, createUserCommand)` method to actually create an instance of your class.

If you are using the [`ValidationPipe`](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#a-built-in-validationpipe) it can automatically transform your plain object to a class if you pass the option `transform: true`:

```
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
async index(@Body() createUserCommand: CreateUserCommand): Promise<User> {
    console.log(createUserCommand);
    return await this.commandBus.execute(createUserCommand);
}
```